# How can i select the standard program in developer.apple.com

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I registered as ios developer in developer.apple.com with my company id. Now i want to test my app in real device. so i follow the tutorial as follows.

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices

In that, we can login into the developer.apple.com/iphone/program/ and select the program as you wish in two programs. But i can't find the standard and enterprise programs. It shows like this...

http://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/create.php

I can't understand how can i go through this and what i select.

Can anyone please solve my problem.

Thanks

Chakradhar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go here: http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/

You have to register for the $99/individual membership to be able to push the app to your physical device. The free membership will not allow you to push your app to the device, only run it in the simulator.

There is also a fairly lengthy process you must go through to be able to get your app onto your device after you register.  Go ahead and register, get approved, and pay your $99.

Next, login here: http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Once logged in, you will see 'iOS Provisioning Portal' on the right. Go there, and it will help through the rest of the process.

Answer (score 1):

You ought to check the "I'm registered as a developer with Apple and would like to enroll in a paid Apple Developer Program." option.

Comment: Thank you for giving reply. I went that process what u told me. To test the app , is there need to complete that process. Why am i asking this, there is the continous filling as purchase program , activate program like this. so , for testing the simple app also , shall i fill that information.